# Sticky is causing others divs to glitch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a navbar with a submenu. The navbar has an image as a logo. Used Javascript to create sticky. The problem is, when I open the submenu and when sticky is active, the logo(image) is glitching. I'm not facing this problem if the logo is pure text. I tried for hours to figure out the problem. Wrapped the entire navbar in multiple combinations of divs but couldn't solve the issue. Further, the glitch occurs at random times- which is freaking me out more. I'm attaching part of my code here. Can anyone tell me what is causing the error

```js
  function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;

function scrollDetect() {
  var lastScroll = 0;
  window.onscroll = function() {
    let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; // Get Current Scroll Value

    if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll) {
      lastScroll = currentScroll;
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      navbar.classList.remove("z-index-999999");
    } else {
      lastScroll = currentScroll;
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
      navbar.classList.add("z-index-999999");
    }

    if (currentScroll < 100) {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      navbar.classList.remove("z-index-999999");
    }

  };
}

scrollDetect();
```

```css
.main-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
  top: 3.7rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5rem;
}


/*Code for Sticky*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s height ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s height ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s height ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
}

.logo img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 11.1rem;
  left: 9%;
  margin-top: -3px;
  width: 330px;
}

.nav-list {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  margin-left: 2.7rem;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 3.8rem;
  left: -34.4rem;
  width: 89.89rem;
  height: 35rem;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 3rem 40px 0 40px;
}

.nav-list>li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.z-index-999999{
z-index: 999999999;
}

.content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a><img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/q_auto:eco/t_product_v1/f_auto/dpr_2.0/w_441,c_limit/9d1635ed-eed0-45b0-b34d-e00468e2f79e/tanjun-easyon-shoes-mplG1H.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="dropdown-item-1">
        <a href="">Men</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
          <ul>
      </li>
      <ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class=content>
  content for scroll
</div>
```

Comment: Really hard to tell what this is _supposed_ to do, from that rudimentary snippet. Sure, something glitchy appears to be happening ... but I can't tell what is actually wanted here. Plus there isn't even enough content to require any scrolling, so unclear how/when sticky is supposed to come into play.

Comment: The above snippet is not my complete code. I do have content to scroll in my main code.  Given how the glitch is random, I thought the error was in the structure of my code. If needed I can provide more code but can you tell what is required?

Comment: Right now this doesn't even appear to _apply_ your "sticky" solution, not in the small version of the rendered snippet, nor the fullscreen display.

Comment: Hey, please check now. However, I don't think the problem is with 'sticky'. Given how the problem does not arise when the logo is pure text- its something else.

Comment: With all the JS code removed, the snippet still behaves the same - so the sticky part is probably indeed not it. The issue appears to be that your sub-menu covers the image ...? With `left: -34.4rem;`, that doesn't seem too surprising here though. But I of course can't tell what made you to use that "magic number" there in the first place.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? is it a simple sticky even on scroll it should be on the top right ?

Comment: Hey, I don't think the problem is with sticky. How my sticky works is- if the user scrolls down, the navbar goes invisible (move -3rem up), until the user scroll up or reaches the end of the webpage. So what I meant when I said that I facethe problem only when sticky is activated is-when the navbar is that at its initial postion, there is not glitch. When the sticky is actived(lets say I scrolled up somewherer before I reached the end of the page) and I open the submenu- it glitches at random time.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can make the logo's positioning consistent by using position: absolute for both the regular and sticky states of the logo. Here's a modified version of your CSS and HTML:

```css
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 9%;
  top: 3px;
}

.sticky .logo {
  top: 10px; /* Adjust the top value as needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a><img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/q_auto:eco/t_product_v1/f_auto/dpr_2.0/w_441,c_limit/9d1635ed-eed0-45b0-b34d-e00468e2f79e/tanjun-easyon-shoes-mplG1H.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <!-- menu -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

By using position: absolute for both states of the logo, you ensure that its positioning remains consistent when the navbar becomes sticky. You may need to adjust the top value in the .sticky .logo selector to fine-tune the logo's position when the navbar is sticky.

Answer (score 0):

- If you asking something like this then it could be done something like this without a lot hassle like `getBoundingClientRect` or `scrollDetect`

```js
let prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
let visible = true;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

    if (currentScrollPos > prevScrollPos) {

      if (visible) {
        navbar.classList.remove("visible");
        navbar.classList.add("hidden");
        visible = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (!visible || currentScrollPos === 0) {
        navbar.classList.remove("hidden");
        navbar.classList.add("visible");
        visible = true;
      }
    }

    prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
  });
  if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
    navbar.classList.remove("hidden");
    navbar.classList.add("visible");
    visible = true;
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-inline: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar .logo {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: inline;
}

.navbar.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.navbar.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    </div>
    <ul>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <section id="home">
      <h1>Welcome to Our Website</h1>
      <p>This is the home section of our website. Scroll down to see more content.</p>
      <p>This is the home section of our website. Scroll down to see more content.</p>
      <p>This is the home section of our website. Scroll down to see more content.</p>
      <p>This is the home section of our website. Scroll down to see more content.</p>
      <p>This is the home section of our website. Scroll down to see more content.</p>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, your code seems to be working but there's a problem when I reach the initial position again. The navbar is not visible when I return to the top. Thanks for the suggestion though. However, like I said, my problem is not with sticky. I don't face the problem when the logo is text. I believe its got be positioning of my elements or their paddings

Answer (score 0):

try using CSS sticky instead of javascript.
Here, I have used `position: sticky` and `top: 0`. `top:0` here means main-navbar with stick when it reaches top: 0, and will scroll till elements before them are in view (for eg: `<br/>` tag).

```css
.main-navbar {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5rem;
}


.logo img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 11.1rem;
  left: 9%;
  margin-top: -3px;
  width: 330px;
}

.nav-list {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  margin-left: 2.7rem;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 3.8rem;
  left: -34.4rem;
  width: 89.89rem;
  height: 35rem;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 3rem 40px 0 40px;
}

.nav-list>li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.z-index-999999{
z-index: 999999999;
}

.content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100rem;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a><img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/q_auto:eco/t_product_v1/f_auto/dpr_2.0/w_441,c_limit/9d1635ed-eed0-45b0-b34d-e00468e2f79e/tanjun-easyon-shoes-mplG1H.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="dropdown-item-1">
        <a href="">Men</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
          <ul>
      </li>
      <ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class=content>
  content for scroll
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'glitch' you are experiencing with the logo when opening the submenu in your sticky navbar could be related to the way the `position: fixed` property affects the rendering of elements when the layout changes. Here are some suggestions to help you troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

1. **Update Your Logo CSS:**

   Instead of using `position: relative` and manual positioning for your logo image, try using `margin-left` and `margin-right` for centering. Modify your `.logo img` CSS like this:

   ```css
   .logo img {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: block;
     width: 330px;
   }
   ```
2. **Use a Container for the Logo and Menu:**

   Wrap your logo and menu in a container div, and apply `display: flex;` to this container. This can help ensure consistent positioning.

   ```html
   <div class="navbar-container">
     <div class="logo">
       <a><img src="your-logo-src.png" alt=""></a>
     </div>
     <nav>
       <!-- Your menu code here -->
     </nav>
   </div>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```css
   .navbar-container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center; /* Vertically center the logo and menu */
     justify-content: space-between; /* Separate the logo and menu */
     height: 4.5rem; /* Adjust the height as needed */
     background-color: red;
   }

   /* Remove the absolute positioning and margins from .logo img */
   .logo img {
     width: 330px;
   }
   ```